# Puma::Server::UNPACK_TCP_STATE_FROM_TCP_INFO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I succefully installed a rails app on my FreeBSD server but when I test `rails s -e production` or `rails s -e development` I get `Read: #<NameError: uninitialized constant Puma::Server::UNPACK_TCP_STATE_FROM_TCP_INFO>` from the Puma server after sending request

I missed a step somewhere ?

PS. I use Rails6 with SqlLite3

config/puma.rb

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Comment: I am not a Puma expert. Yet how do you "make a query in your browser". What url do you type in navbar ? Also does it work in development environment ?

Comment: In the url bar browser `public_ip_server:3000` after I get `Read: #<NameError: uninitialized constant Puma::Server::UNPACK_TCP_STATE_FROM_TCP_INFO>` from Puma.

Comment: Just to know if this is not a production setup issue. When you start Puma in development with `rails s` and get to url `localhost:3000` does Puma returns an error ?

Comment: In development environment I have nothing, my browser return a site unavailable error and my Puma server don't catch any request

Comment: What do you mean by "Puma doesn't catch any request" ? If this is local (development) `localhost:3000` is sufficient to query your app locally. I suspect there is a problem with your production setup. Also if your production setup is fine this could be a problem of sockets as shown here in Puma source code : https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/server.rb#L182 There are a few threads about it

Comment: I made `curl -i -X HEAD http://localhost:3000` with Puma in developement env I got the same error than in production (Read: #<NameError: uninitialized constant Puma::Server::UNPACK_TCP_STATE_FROM_TCP_INFO>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made monkey patch that seems to work.
(This problem happens on FreeBSD, not on Mac OS X)

Place this content in an initializer file. For example: `config/initializers/puma_missing_constant_monkey_patch.rb`.

```rb
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  if defined?(::Puma) && !Object.const_defined?('Puma::Server::UNPACK_TCP_STATE_FROM_TCP_INFO')
    ::Puma::Server::UNPACK_TCP_STATE_FROM_TCP_INFO = "C".freeze
  end
end
```

It just defines the missing constant. I've got no clue if it breaks something else. On the other hand Puma uses a constant that isn't defined. The define of this constant in Puma (lib/puma/server.rb) is conditional.

Comment: Just filed an issue about this: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2556

Comment: Thank you very much, the patch work correctly for me